# d3.js chart area filling with different colors

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm attempting to fill the area under the graph with different colors, depending on x value ranges, say for example, for x values 0 to 10 yellow, from 10 to 20 red and so on. Is there a way to do that?

My javascript for single fill color is

```
var m = 80; 
var w = 900 - 3*m;
var h = 600- 3*m; 

var x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, w]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([h, 0]);
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.time; }));
y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.points; }));

var line = d3.svg.line()
.x(function(d) { 
return x(d.time); 
})

.y(function(d) { 
return y(d.points); 
})

var graph = d3.select("#graph").append("svg:svg")
           .attr("width", w+3*m)
           .attr("height", h+3*m)
           .append("svg:g")
           .attr("transform", "translate(" + 1.5*m + "," + 1.5*m + ")");

var area = d3.svg.area()
.x(function(d) { return x(d.time); })
.y0(h)
.y1(function(d) { return y(d.points); });

graph.append("path")
.datum(data)
.attr("class", "area")
.attr("d", area)
.style("fill","steelblue");
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You basically have two options for doing this.

- You can define separate areas for the different colours.
- You can define a single area and use a gradient to simulate different colours.

The second one is probably easier, as you don't need to draw any separate paths, you can simply fill the one like you're currently doing.

For the gradient, you would need to define the stops (i.e. colour changes) to correspond to the values. In particular, you would need to introduce two stops at the same place to make it appear like the colour is changing suddenly. More information on gradients [here](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_grad_linear.asp). The code would look something like this.

```
var grad = graph.append("defs")
     .append("linearGradient")
     .attr("id", "grad");
grad.append("stop").attr("offset", "0%").attr("stop-color", "yellow");
grad.append("stop").attr("offset", "10%").attr("stop-color", "yellow");
grad.append("stop").attr("offset", "10%").attr("stop-color", "red");
grad.append("stop").attr("offset", "20%").attr("stop-color", "red");
// etc

graph.append("path")
     .style("fill", "url(#grad)");
```

The positions of the stops would be determined by your scale.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work! But if the number of differently colored areas and stops is variable, depending on the data I plot, how can that be done?

Comment: Same thing. Everything is added in the code and you can of course use data to define that as well, e.g. `grad.selectAll("stop").data(data).enter()...`.