# Different gradient for every area

Tags: d3.js

So I'm trying to create a bump chart, but where the color also represents a variable, which changes over time. But this change is different for every area. The code I have so far is:

```
chart = {
  const svg = d3.create("svg")
  .attr("viewBox", [0, 0, width, height])
  .style("overflow", "visible");

  svg.append("g")
  .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
  .call(yAxis);

 const areaBand = d3.area()
.x((d, i) => x(data.dates[i]))
.y0(d => y(d.middle - d.votes/2))
.y1(d => y(d.middle + d.votes/2))

  const path = svg.append("g")
  .attr("stroke", "white")
  .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
  .attr("stroke-miterlimit", 1)
.selectAll("path")
.data(data.series)
.join("path")
.attr("d", d => areaBand(d.values))

return svg.node();}
```

Which results in this: [image]

Then I tried to change the colors with this, but that obviously changes the area to the color of the first year.

```
 .attr("fill", d=> d3.interpolateRdBu((d.values[0].diff+1)/2))
```

[image]
I tried adding the code from this stackoverflow question: [d3.js chart area filling with different colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19114896/d3-js-chart-area-filling-with-different-colors)
So I did this as a test:

```
chart = {
  
....

  const areaBand = d3.area()
    .x((d, i) => x(data.dates[i]))
    .y0(d => y(d.middle - d.votes/2))
    .y1(d => y(d.middle + d.votes/2))
  

  const path = svg.append("g")
      .attr("stroke", "white")
      .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
      .attr("stroke-miterlimit", 1)
    .selectAll("g")
      .data(data.series)
    .enter().append("g")
  
  path.append("path")
    .attr("d", d => areaBand(d.values))
  .attr("fill", "url(#grad)")
  
    //.attr("fill", d=> d3.interpolateRdBu((d.values[0].diff+1)/2))
  var grad = path.append("defs")
     .append("linearGradient")
     .attr("id", "grad");
grad.append("stop").attr("offset", "0%").attr("stop-color", function(d) {return d.values[0].diff < 0 ? "red" : "blue";});
grad.append("stop").attr("offset", "10%").attr("stop-color", "yellow");
grad.append("stop").attr("offset", "10%").attr("stop-color", "red");
grad.append("stop").attr("offset", "20%").attr("stop-color", "red");

  

  return svg.node();
}
```

But then I get the same color for every area again. [image]

So ideally, I want some combination of both solutions. But I have no clue how to achieve that anymore. Anyone have any tips?

Ps, my data looks like this, if that makes sense:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the idea would be to have a different gradient for each path. Taking from [Lars' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19114896/d3-js-chart-area-filling-with-different-colors?noredirect=1&lq=1), we could create a gradient for every path, with the position of the stops determined by your scale.

To do so, we need a scale that tells us where we are in the current gradient at index i. For example, if we have three values, then this scale will act this way:

```
i | gradientScale(i)
--------------------
0 | 0
1 | 50
2 | 100
```

This allows us to get the value of offset each time. If i is 1, then the value of the offset will be "50%".

This way, you could have a color function that colors based on the value, like in your example.

```
var color = d => d3.interpolateRdBu((d.diff+1)/2) // color here...

var innerLength = data.values[0].values.length
var gradientScale = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(Array.from(Array(innerLength).keys())) // [0,1,2,...,length-1]
  .range([0, 100])

data.series.forEach((values,i) => {
  var grad = graph.append("defs")
    .append("linearGradient")
    .attr("id", (d,i) => `grad-${i}`)

  grad.selectAll("stop")
    .data(values)
    .append("stop")
    .attr("offset", `${gradientScale(i)}`)
    .attr("stop-color", d => color(d))
})
```

Once you've done that, for your path, we need to associate each path with the corresponding gradient we just generated:

```
path.append("path")
  .attr("d", d => areaBand(d.values))
  .attr("fill", (d,i) => `url(#grad-${i})`)
```

Comment: I decided to hardcode this part: ``` grad.selectAll("stop").data(values)
    .append("stop")
    .attr("offset",(d,i) => `${gradientScale(i)}`)
    .attr("stop-color", d=> color(d))```

There is an error somewhere, but havent been able to find it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I think the error was doing ``` `(d,i)=>`${gradientScale(i)}` ```, because it remplaces the earlier i. You can do the string directly - I've edited my answer.